# Angular dynamic nested key ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, ngmodel, primeng-table

How to use dynamic key in ngModel?
I am using the primeNg library and i'm trying to bind a dynamic key to the ngModel

this is the html template

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="data">
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

this is the "cols" variable

```
cols = [
      { field: 'variables.code', header: 'Code' },
      { field: 'variables.name', header: 'Name' },
];
```

and this is an example of data

```
[{
  "variables": {
     "code": "D44D5",
     "name": "keyboard"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below, where you can split `col.field.split('.') as fieldName` and then form `ngModel` like this `rowData[fieldName[0]][fieldName[1]]`.

```
<div *ngFor="let rowData of rows;">
  <div *ngFor="let col of columns;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="getValue(rowData, col.field) as fieldName">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fieldName" />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
getValue(rowData, fieldPath) {
    const fieldName = fieldPath
      .replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'.')
      .split('.')
      .filter(i => i);
    console.log(fieldName);
    const field = fieldName.reduce((acc, f) => acc[f], rowData)
    return field;
}
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4jpvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Note:- Above would work for both the usecases, when object has nested structure.

Comment: The real problem is that col.field has more nested keys

Comment: Noted, let me check, whether this solution can be extended.

Comment: @Mitinoh can there be an array inside a row value, form example `variables.code[0].somethingElse`?

Comment: @Mitinoh updated answer, please have a look

Comment: Yeah there can be an array inside a row value

Comment: @Mitinoh check updated answer, added nested object access support

Comment: I'm getting this error 
` Cannot use variable 'fieldName' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template
variables are read-only. `

Comment: I tried your solution posted on stackblitz, but unfortunatly the ngModel is not working, casue if you add {{ rows[0].variables.name }} in the template, it's not updating

Comment: @Mitinoh you can use `getValue(rowData, col.field)` function when printing value as well. Unsure what exactly you're doing

Comment: Parker, this is what i'm trying to do https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otzjnt?file=src/app/app.component.html, what about the  ` Cannot use variable 'fieldName' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only. `

Comment: Sorry don't completely understand, what you mean here?

Comment: When i change the value inside the input i was expecting to see it also change outside at line 9.

Comment: I got you, thanks for explaining

Comment: Thank tou for the patience.

Comment: how about [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgxecw)